# Jquery UI Autocomplete - How to pass the variable from Jquery to ashx handler

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete, generic-handler

I am using Jquery UI Multiple Values Autocomplete and I'm making the request to Server:

```
.autocomplete({
          source: function(request, response) {
              $.getJSON("handlers/autocomplete.ashx", {
                  term: extractLast(request.term)
              }, response);
          },
```

How to I get back the value of `term` in my .ashx handler?

I have tried `Request.Form["TextBox1"]` but I'm getting `object reference not set to an intance of an object` error. Is there any way I can get it directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass TextBox1 value with the url

```
.autocomplete({
          source: function(request, response) {
              $.getJSON("handlers/autocomplete.ashx?TextBox1=curtxt", {
                  term: extractLast(request.term)
              }, response);
          },
```

Read TextBox1 from Handlers
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

```
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;

string txtval = request["TextBox1"];

   }
```